# Zabbix 3.4, Oracle Linux 7.4: Error with php-mbstring and php-bcmath

Tags: linux, php, zabbix

I have OS

```
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="7.4"
ID="ol"
VERSION_ID="7.4"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 7.4"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:4:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 7"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.4
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.4
```

Tried to install zabbix 3.4

```
 rpm -Uvh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.4/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.4-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
```

and

```
yum install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql
```

and returned error

```
Error: Package: zabbix-web-3.4.1-1.el7.noarch (zabbix)
           Requires: php-mbstring
Error: Package: zabbix-web-3.4.1-1.el7.noarch (zabbix)
           Requires: php-bcmath
```

How to solve problem?

p.s.

tried to installed

```
sudo yum install php-mbstring
```

returned

```
Loaded plugins: ulninfo
No package php-mbstring available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

tried to search

```
[root@zabbixapp01 zabbix]# yum search mbstring
Loaded plugins: ulninfo
Warning: No matches found for: mbstring
No matches found
[root@zabbixapp01 zabbix]# yum search bcmath
Loaded plugins: ulninfo
Warning: No matches found for: bcmath
No matches found
```

Comment: Try searching for the package: `yum search mbstring` and `yum search bcmath`.

Comment: yum search mbstring
Loaded plugins: ulninfo
Warning: No matches found for: mbstring
No matches found
yum search bcmath
Loaded plugins: ulninfo
Warning: No matches found for: bcmath
No matches found

Answer (score 0):

These packages are in the RHEL "optional" repository. Given that "Oracle Linux" is just a renamed RHEL, you need to add a copy of that repo.

Installing RPMs directly is not suggested - instead, add this repo and install packages with `yum`: http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/optional/latest/x86_64/index.html .